# Teradata gets division wrong?

Tags: teradata, rank, percentile, dense-rank

I have a coworker that doesn't want to include null rows in a percentile rank. The default Teradata function seems to just treat null as the lowest number in the set, so I decided to do the math manually. I started using the below query to test out my equation

```
drop table tmp;

create multiset volatile table tmp (
  num byteint
) primary index (num)
  on commit preserve rows
;

insert into tmp
values (1)
;insert into tmp
values (2)
;insert into tmp
values (1)
;insert into tmp
values (4)
;insert into tmp
values (null)
;insert into tmp
values (4)
;insert into tmp
values (null)
;insert into tmp
values (2)
;insert into tmp
values (9)
;insert into tmp
values (null)
;insert into tmp
values (10)
;insert into tmp
values (10)
;insert into tmp
values (11)
;

select
  num,
  case
    when num is null then 0
    else cast(dense_rank() over (partition by case when num is not null then 1 else 2 end order by num) as number)
  end as str_rnk,
  q.nn,
  str_rnk/q.nn as pct_rnk
from tmp
cross join (
    select cast(count(num) as number) as nn from tmp
) q
order by num
;
```

So what I expect to see in result set is this:

```
num   str_rnk  nn  pct_rnk
null        0  10        0
null        0  10        0
null        0  10        0
   1        1  10      0.1
   1        1  10      0.1
   2        2  10      0.2
   2        2  10      0.2
   4        3  10      0.3
   4        3  10      0.3
   9        4  10      0.4
  10        5  10      0.5
  10        5  10      0.5
```

But I'm getting a result that looks like it did a regular `rank` instead of a `dense_rank`, like this:

```
num   str_rnk  nn  pct_rnk
null        0  10        0
null        0  10        0
null        0  10        0
   1        1  10      0.1
   1        1  10      0.1
   2        2  10      0.3
   2        2  10      0.3
   4        3  10      0.5
   4        3  10      0.5
   9        4  10      0.7
  10        5  10      0.8
  10        5  10      0.8
```

I know I could set the rank in a subquery and It would calculate the way I expect it to, but why isn't it doing it the way I have it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JNevill noted this is a bug, you should open an incident with Teradata support:

```
SELECT
   num,
   -- cast to FLOAT or DECIMAL works as expected
   Cast(Dense_Rank() Over (ORDER BY num) AS NUMBER) AS a,
   a AS b
FROM tmp

 num    a    b
----  ---  ---
   ?    1    1
   ?    1    1
   ?    1    1
   1    2    4
   1    2    4
   2    3    6
   2    3    6
   4    4    8
   4    4    8
   9    5   10
  10    6   11
  10    6   11
  11    7   13
```

But adding `QUALIFY a<>b` returns an empty result :-)

The original calculation for `PERCENT_RANK` is based on

```
Cast(Rank() Over (ORDER BY num) -1 AS DEC(18,6)) / Count(*) Over ()
```

If you want to exclude NULLs you can switch to `Count(num)` and `NULLS LAST`:

```
SELECT
   num,
   CASE
      WHEN num IS NOT NULL 
      THEN Cast(Dense_Rank() Over (ORDER BY num NULLS LAST) AS DECIMAL(18,6)) 
      ELSE 0
   END AS str_rnk,
   str_rnk / Count(num) Over ()
FROM tmp
```

Or using that slick `num * 0` trick:

```
SELECT
   num,
   Coalesce(Dense_Rank()
            Over (ORDER BY num NULLS LAST) 
             * (num * 0 +1.000000), 0) AS str_rnk,
   str_rnk / Count(num) Over ()
FROM tmp
```

Comment: It's a relief to hear that you think this is a bug. I was trying to think through "why" it might be doing this and couldn't come up with any good reason.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't answer your question. It's not the division that's an issue, it seems to be some oddball issue running that CAST and Dense_Rank twice in the same SELECT.

Consider:

```
select
  num,
  case
    when num is null then 0
    else cast(dense_rank() over (partition by case when num is not null then 1 else 2 end order by num) as number)
  end as str_rnk,

  case
    when num is null then 0
    else cast(dense_rank() over (partition by case when num is not null then 1 else 2 end order by num) as number)
  end as str_rnk2
from tmp
cross join (
    select cast(count(num) as number) as nn from tmp
) q;


+--------+---------+----------+
|  num   | str_rnk | str_rnk2 |
+--------+---------+----------+
| 1      |       1 |        1 |
| 1      |       1 |        1 |
| 2      |       2 |        3 |
| 2      |       2 |        3 |
| 4      |       3 |        5 |
| 4      |       3 |        5 |
| 9      |       4 |        7 |
| 10     |       5 |        8 |
| 10     |       5 |        8 |
| 11     |       6 |       10 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Since the CAST isn't necessary here:

```
select
  num,

  case
    when num is null then 0
    else dense_rank() over (partition by case when num is not null then 1 else 2 END order by num) 
  end as str_rnk,

  case
    when num is null then 0
    else dense_rank() over (partition by case when num is not null then 1 else 2 END order by num) 
  end as str_rnk2
from tmp
cross join (
    select cast(count(num) as number) as nn from tmp
) q;

+--------+---------+----------+
|  num   | str_rnk | str_rnk2 |
+--------+---------+----------+
| 1      |       1 |        1 |
| 1      |       1 |        1 |
| 2      |       2 |        2 |
| 2      |       2 |        2 |
| 4      |       3 |        3 |
| 4      |       3 |        3 |
| 9      |       4 |        4 |
| 10     |       5 |        5 |
| 10     |       5 |        5 |
| 11     |       6 |        6 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
| <null> |       0 |        0 |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Your query, with a quick rewrite:

```
select
  num,
  case
    when num is null then 0
    else dense_rank() over (partition by num * 0 order by num) 
    end as str_rnk, 
  str_rnk * 1.0/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY num * 0) as pct_rnk
from tmp
order by num
;

+--------+---------+---------+
|  num   | str_rnk | pct_rnk |
+--------+---------+---------+
| <null> |       0 |     0.0 |
| <null> |       0 |     0.0 |
| <null> |       0 |     0.0 |
| 1      |       1 |     0.1 |
| 1      |       1 |     0.1 |
| 2      |       2 |     0.2 |
| 2      |       2 |     0.2 |
| 4      |       3 |     0.3 |
| 4      |       3 |     0.3 |
| 9      |       4 |     0.4 |
| 10     |       5 |     0.5 |
| 10     |       5 |     0.5 |
| 11     |       6 |     0.6 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

Or if you want to get the CASE statement out of there completely:

```
select
  num,
  dense_rank() over (partition by num * 0 order by num) * (num * 0 + 1.0) as str_rnk,  
  str_rnk/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY num * 0) as pct_rnk
from tmp
order by num;
```

Comment: Good catch on the double cast thing, removing one of them gets the job done, but there are some TD quiks at play. `count(*)` includes nulls, which is not what I'm going for. Either the `str_rnk` or `nn` have to be some sort of decimal-accepting type or the result is all 0's in `pct_rnk`. I've heard `number` does calculations most accurately? The `*(num*0+1)` is returning nulls and I need 0's for display purposes, but I could use a `zeroifnull` function. Lastly, I put the ocunt in the subquery to ensure it only ran once. I'm sure the DBMS is optimized for stuff like that, but I like to be sure.

Comment: `num*0` returns either a 0 or a NULL for your grouping. It's quicker then the CASE statement. `* (num*0+1)` multiplies the result time 1, unless it's null, then it makes the whole result null eliminating the need for the outer CASE statement. Run that last one and I think you'll see what you need. `The 1.0` forces the calculation to take one decimal place into account so the cast isnt' necessary.

Comment: I'm definitely going to use multiplication in the inner case, but the `* (num*0+1.0)` returns a null, where I need it to be 0 in the end. I can use a `zeroifnull` function, but I assume this is just a wrapper for a case statement to begin with.

Comment: Yea  you could totally just wrap that whole thing in `zeroifnull()` or go back to the longer case statement. I think the CPU usage would be a draw between the two.

Comment: The `num * 0` trick is slick :-) But I don't think there will be a large CPU difference...